# Четырёхзначные числа последовательности

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, подскажите, у меня вот такое задание!

> Программа выводящая на экран все четырёхзначные числа последовательности 1000 1003 1006 1009 1012 1015 ….

Правильно ли написан код, или что не правильно посоветуйте, что можно изменить или дописать?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int sum = 1000;
        for (int i = 4; i <= 9999; i = i + 4) {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        System.out.println("Четырехзначные числа последовательности - " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое для вас - сделать вот так:

```
for (int i = 1000; i <= 9999; i=i+3) { 
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

На счет "вам надо определять число разрядов в числе" - Можно конечно придумать вместо i <= 9999 что-нибудь вроде

```
Math.log10(new Integer(i).doubleValue())<5;
```

Или

```
String.valueOf(i).lenght()<5;
```

Или еще что-нибудь...

Но смысл? Зачем каждый раз для проверки уходить от int к объектам, вызывать у этих объектов метод, а потом производить сравнение двух чисел, если можно просто провести сравнение двух чисел???

Comment: Спасибо за ответ "Sasha121"

Можно тему закрывать нашел ответ на свой вопрос!!!

Answer (score 1):

Во первых у вас там шаг 4, а по условию шаг между числами 3.
Во вторых, результаты собирайте в массив что ли или стразу внутри цикла печатайте.
В третьих вы вообще считаете сумму числе от 4-х до 9999 (с шагом 4), а не выводите числа.

Вам по идее надо начать цикл с 1000, идти по нему с шагом 3 и печатать числа. Если нужно все числа вывести, вам надо определять число разрядов в числе (что вы поставили 9999 это халтура :) ), если достигните пятизначного, то надо останавливать цикл.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ "DigitalDemiurge"